# rails helper css class change

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a helper function in which class is shown when a specific controller is open.

Helper:

```
     def cssclass
     'class="tab_gen_active3"' if controller_name == "user_brands"

     end
```

I am having difficulty to apply 'else' in which "tab_gen3" css class is activated when controller_name = "user_categories". Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
controller_name == "user_brands" ? 'class="tab_gen_active3"' : ''
```

Comment: Great. Works like charm. I don't know how i missed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more elegant solution - add conditional class to helper method:

```
def cond_class(condition, true_class, false_class = '')
  condition ? true_class : false_class
end
```

and use it in view like this - im my case it haml:

```
.example-div{:class => cond_class(controller_name == 'user_brands', 'tab_gen_active3')}
```